# Is there a quicker way of iterating through and removing specific rows in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently using Bat (https://github.com/Kitware/bat) to read in Bro (https://www.bro.org/) log files and convert them into Pandas dataframes.

One of the things I'm working on is some frequency analysis of DNS lookups. This output shows the size of an hours worth of Bro dns data from one of my hosts, so you might get an idea of the amount of data I'm working with.

```
bro_df.info()

<class 'bat.log_to_dataframe.LogToDataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1013219 entries, 2018-01-03 08:59:53.250328 to 2018-01-03 09:59:51.672011
Data columns (total 23 columns):
AA             1013219 non-null bool
RA             1013219 non-null bool
RD             1013219 non-null bool
TC             1013219 non-null bool
TTLs           1013219 non-null object
Z              1013219 non-null int64
answers        1013219 non-null object
id.orig_h      1013219 non-null object
id.orig_p      1013219 non-null int64
id.resp_h      1013219 non-null object
id.resp_p      1013219 non-null int64
proto          1013219 non-null object
qclass         1013219 non-null int64
qclass_name    1013219 non-null object
qtype          1013219 non-null int64
qtype_name     1013219 non-null object
query          1013219 non-null object
rcode          1013219 non-null int64
rcode_name     1013219 non-null object
rejected       1013219 non-null bool
rtt            1013219 non-null timedelta64[ns]
trans_id       1013219 non-null int64
uid            1013219 non-null object
dtypes: bool(5), int64(7), object(10), timedelta64[ns](1)
memory usage: 151.7+ MB
```

I do some quick and easy stuff like dropping unnecessary columns and such but this is still quite a large dataframe to work with.

In order to do proper frequency analysis of the lookups I'm also trying to remove 'known good', or whitelisted domains, from the dataframe and this is where things get *really* slow. Since I'm fairly new to Pandas I fear that I might be doing this in a less than ideal way, to put it politely.

My approach is as follows for the removal of the whitelisted stuff - I've removed some internal DNS info to protect the innocent:

```
whitelist = ['-', '(empty)', 'in-addr.arpa', '.google.com', '.akamai.net', 
             '.akamaiedge.net', '.apple.com', '.contoso.msft']

for idx, row in bro_df.iterrows():
    for item in whitelist:
        if row['query'].endswith(item):
            bro_df.drop(idx, inplace=True)
```

This takes a very long time to run through even after I scrubbed the data down to quite a bit less than what the original bro_df.info() output above shows. This one log file reflects one hours worth of captured DNS queries but removing the whitelisted stuff takes much longer than an hour so I'm fighting a losing battle here.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers, Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), for match end of strings use `$` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'query':['-','dsds -','- sdsd']})
print (df)
    query
0       -
1  dsds -
2  - sdsd

#() are escaped for remove warning 
whitelist = ['-', '\(empty\)', 'in-addr.arpa', '.google.com', '.akamai.net', 
             '.akamaiedge.net', '.apple.com', '.contoso.msft']


pat = '|'.join([x + '$' for x in whitelist])

df = df[~df['query'].str.contains(pat)]
print (df)
    query
2  - sdsd
```